# Always include python and numpy both in build and in run, in meta.yaml requirements section?

Tags: python, numpy, conda

I am building a purely Python conda package that uses numpy as an import.

Based on Conda's [meta.yaml documentation](https://conda.io/docs/user-guide/tasks/build-packages/define-metadata.html#requirements-section), it isn't entirely clear to me where python and numpy are to be included in the `requirements:` section.

- Do they *have* to be included in the `build:` subsection?
- If so, do they also have to be duplicated in the `run:` section?

If the answer is yes to both, then the `requirements:` section would look something like this:

```
requirements:
  build:
    - python 
    - numpy
  run:
    - python
    - numpy
    - otherpackage1
    - otherpackage2
    - ...
```

Is this right? Or is the duplication superfluous? Or can the `build:` section be omitted, and python and numpy only be included in the `run:` section?

Comment: How is your package installed (what is your `build.sh` or `bld.bat` or `build:script` contents)? If you run `python setup.py install` or some variant thereof, then Python has to be a build-time dependency. For numpy, I think you might just have to try it both ways and see the result :-)

Comment: @darthbith Ah, okay, that's what the `build:` section is for. Yes, my `bld.bat` is just the default `python setup.py install`.

Comment: In that case, I don't think that numpy will be a build-time dependency for a pure-Python package, but conda also doesn't allow setuptools to install any packages, so I'm not sure what will happen :-) Also, see here about the install command: https://conda-forge.org/docs/meta.html#single-version-externally-managed